# Permission uncertainty in Greenplum

Tags: privileges, greenplum, sql-grant

I am using Greenplum 6.8(Postgres 9.4) open source, I created role that have all permission on a schema, after assigning that role to user I added a new table in schema but user is not able to access that table. I have to refresh my role definition to access that new table, role definition is like below:

```
grant usage on schema <schema_name> to <rolename>;
grant select on all tables in schema <schema_name> to <rolename>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schema_name> GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO <rolename>;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, there is a flag in its configuration `automatic_sp_privileges`; however I am also looking for same in Greenplum.